# "Run as administrator" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, domain, administrator

In Windows 7, which of the following accounts would have the "Run as Administrator" option showing for executable files?

1. local account not in the local or
   domain administrator group
2. local account in the local
   administrator group
3. local account in the domain
   administrator group
4. domain account not in the local or
   domain administrator group
5. domain account in the local
   administrator group
6. domain account in the domain
   administrator group

Comment: even if you don't see the run as admin if you shift+right click you should see it.  if not the ctrl+right click will do it.  Other then that I don't know the answer to your question.

Comment: Is this a curiosity or are you trying to accomplish something else (like preventing someone from using it)?

Comment: Both. I am trying to understand why an OCX appears not to be registering properly and causing an error in some software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Run as Administrator" should appear for all accounts that are running with UAC enabled.

All users have access to the functionality, either by Shift + Right-clicking a program, or by using the `runas` command.  Nonmembers of the local Administrators group will need to enter credentials in order to use this.  Depending on your system settings, members of the local Administrators group don't need credentials, they just need to approve the elevation.

Comment: the feature can also be disabled through group policy though

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, Explorer.exe and Internet Explorer will not let you run as a domain administrator if you are logged in as a lesser privileged user.